# Looking for assistance in a authorized to edit method

Tags: ruby, sinatra-activerecord

```
  def authorized_to_edit?(review_info)
    set_review_info
    if  @user.id != @review_info.user.id
      redirect "/users/#{@user.id}"
    else
      redirect 'review_entries/user_review'
    end
  end
```

I am trying to allow users that own the review_info can edit it and users who do not can view all review_info. Only the owner of the object can ever edit the object.

I am thinking of  something like

`if @user.id != @review_info.user.id`

Comment: `@user.id != @review_info.user_id` is a little faster since it avoids loading the user model on the other end. This is what tools like [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) can solve for you. One thing to node here is you shouldn't just gate the redirect, you should gate the pages relating to that resource. Don't forget to lock down actions that can be accessed by guessing the URL.

Comment: You may want to invert the logic here and reverse the blocks. Right now the else triggers if the user is not *not* equal to something, a double-negative. These can get mind-bendingly confusing.

Comment: Very good points so

Comment: See reversing the blocks just keeps me fulfilling the If only. My brain is missing something. Essentially I have multiple users and I want my authorize method to check when they click on a review it either shows them the page with the edit button or the one without it depending on authorize.

Comment: I'd expect a method like this to return `true` or `false` depending on their ability. I would not expect it to redirect. Somewhere you'd check before showing that this returns `true` and if not do the redirect there. A method like this should only provide an opinion, not take action.

Comment: Another thing to note is you have an argument `review_info` but refer to `@review_info` inside the method. Did you mean to use the argument?